# Unable to understand value of PHP associate array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am unable to understand last value `'changes'    => [ ],` of associate array.

```
$table_report = array(
        'table_name' => $table,
        'rows'       => 0,
        'change'     => 0,
        'changes'    => [ ],
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

`[]` is an alternative syntax to `array()` introduced in PHP 5.4

`[]` is just an empty array.

---

This

```
$table_report = array(
  'table_name' => $table,
  'rows'       => 0,
  'change'     => 0,
  'changes'    => array()
);
```

is equivalent to

```
$table_report = [
  'table_name' => $table,
  'rows'       => 0,
  'change'     => 0,
  'changes'    => []
];
```